# How to create grid in GIMP (not sure if the filter is good)

Tags: gimp, grids

I'm a beginner to GIMP, and I'd like to create a grid.

I searched Google and all it gave me was to use the `Filter` > `Render` > `Grid` plugin, but for my job all I want to do is something like this:

Let's say I have a square image that's 1530 x 1530, and I want the grid to be an 8 x 8 matrix with grid lines that are 1px wide. I don't want to calculate the right spacing on each grid cell as the grid filter gives me; I just want GIMP to calculate the right spacing and grid line width for this image.

Is there a way to do it right?

Comment: Documentation on the below plugin is [here](http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-grid.html). Note if you want to create a grid of guides you can use [this plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/12003)

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of how the grid plug-in works:
[image: Gimp Grid Filter Screenshot]
This screenshot depicts a four-square grid where each line has a width of 1 pixel.  There is no offset around the border.  The intersections are 0 so that lines smoothly intersect each other.

The spacing is the part that you seem to be having trouble with.  First, you should set it in percent by clicking the drop-down menu next to it and selecting the percent symbol.  This allows you to give each line a proportionate spacing that you don't have to calculate.  When regarding percentage, 
[image: Percent example]
this is considered to be 100% horizontal, 100% vertical.  This means that there will be a gap between each line equal to 100% of the image's width and height.  If you take 100 here and divide it by 8 (as in your case), then you will get the number of lines you wish to have expressed as a percentage (in this case, 12.5%).  If you insert 12.5, 12.5 then each line will have a width and height of 12.5% of the total image, so that you end up with an 8x8 grid.  This method works for other grid sizes.  You can click the chain icon below the spacing category (as seen in the first screenshot) to set the widths and heights between each line independently.

For example, if you wanted a 5x3 grid, you would use:
100 / 5 = 20 for horizontal lines, and
100 / 3 = 33.33 for vertical lines.
The screenshot below illustrates this.
[image: 5x3 grid]